# Javascript and timing, specifically with callbacks

Tags: javascript, callback

I want to make sure I understand callbacks properly, and javascript timing etc. in general.

Say my code looks like this, is it guaranteed to execute in order?

```
SetList();  // initializes the var _list

Some.Code(_list, function(data) {

      // update list

});

DoSomething(_list);   // operates on _list
```

**Update**

What I am seeing is SetList calls, then DoSomething, then Some.Code.

Some.Code calls another function. so:

```
Some.Code(_list, function() {

    //load _list from ajax request
    Other.Code.WithCallback(_list, function(){....});

});
```

**I guess to fix this, I have to add DoSomething to the inner function as another callback?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetList()`, `Some.Code()` and `DoSomething()` will execute in that order, one after the other.  The anonymous function passed as the second argument to `Some.Code()` could be called during the execution of `Some.Code()` (before the function returns and `DoSomething()` is called) or it could be called at a later time by another function, and event handler or timer, it all depends on when you specified it to be called.

---

Since you're using ajax, the request to the remote server is made on a separate thread, so the executing javascript thread continues to run and call other functions until a response (or, more specifically, for the `onreadystatechange` event to fire).  When the ready state of the ajax request changes, its `readystatechange` event handler is queued to be called -- meaning it will execute as soon as all currently executing scripts finish.

If you want `DoSomething()` to execute after the response is received via ajax, you should run it to the end of your callback function instead.

Comment: How can I ensure that the anonymous function is executed before the call to DoSomething(_list); ?

Comment: @Blankman: You would have to call it at some point during the `Some.Code()` method, before that method returns.

Answer (score -1):

That code would execute in order:

SetList(), then Some.Code(), then function(data), then DoSomething().

JavaScript is single-threaded, and executes in order. The only way that things would happen out of sync is if you set an interval/timer within Some.Code() or function(data) that called another function.

If you had:

```
var i=0;
functionCall() //some long process that sets i=1;
if (i==1) { alert("In Order!"); } else { alert("Out of Order!"); }
```

That would alert *"In Order,"* But if you had:

```
var i=0;
setTimeout(functionCall, 1000) //some long process that sets i=1;
if (i==1) { alert("In Order!"); } else { alert("Out of Order!"); }
```

That would execute *"Out of Order,"* because the third line would execute before functionCall() is called.

**Updated Answer**

Because you are using Ajax, I'm guessing you are making an asynchronous call, which is the reason for the delay. You have a callback function, but it's still waiting to be called back, so Javascript moves on to execute the next line while it waits.

To execute in the order you want, you'll need to do this:

```
SetList();  // initilizes the var _list
Some.Code(_list, function(data) {
  // update list
  DoSomething(_list);   // operates on _list
});
```

This way, you can ensure that DoSomething() is called when your callback method is called, and not before.

Comment: function(data) does *not* get executed in the order you have said. It is passed as an argument to Some.Code, and could be executed anytime, or not at all, there is not enough information to say.

Comment: Whether function(data) is called is actually besides the point. As you can see in the the structure of function(data), adding the call to DoSomething(_list) means that it becomes part of the call back method - and triggers after everything preceeding it, ensuring the order desired.